# Why does HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name return blank

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization

I created a site.  It is an internal site.  It is a .NET 4.0 site.  I would like to grab the username using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name of the person browsing the site.  There isnt a login page since it is internal.  I am not sure what I am missing.  Do I need the following in my webconfig:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<authorization>
  <allow users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

and this:

```
  <system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

Comment: You don't get users login names that want to remain anonymous without forcing authentication of some sort - if thats what you were hoping to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It comes up blank when unauthenticated.  You can verify this by also doing:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Check your authentication level in IIS, is it set to enable windows authentication there too?

Answer (score 9):

In iis disable anonymous access and enable integrated windows security for you web application.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you do need, at least the

```
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
```

part is required if you are using Integrated Windows Auth.

After that, you should be able to grab the username of the person logged in.

No, you don't need:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

Comment: I changed my webconfig to just have <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>, but still no username. Browsing the site from my computer, I am expecting to see my username (that user I am signed into the machine with).  Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Did you configure integrated windows auth at the app level in IIS?

Answer (score 3):

In IIS, go to Sites \ Default Website \ [Your Website].

Select Authentication option and disable Anonymous Authentication.

Answer (score 2):

In my case removing `<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />` line from `web.config` helps.

I also have `<authentication mode="Forms" />` in `<system.web>` section.