# ASP MVC Application User Null using User.Identity.GetUserId

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok so I have a relationship between the ApplicationUser and QuestionResults, my models are as below, the userId nor the UserName is retrieved, but I really need the UserId setup as a foreignKey on the QuestionResults entity.

**Any help is much appreciated** the error that I am receiving is as below:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in STRA.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
on these lines of code:

qr.User.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
qr.User.UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
```

**Models**

```
public class QuestionResult
    {
        public QuestionResult()
        {
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            DateModified = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
        public int QuestionScore { get; set; }
        //navigation properties
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        //public ICollection<CategoryResult> CategoryResult { get; set; }
        //public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        //public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        //public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Industry { get; set; }
        public string GlobalRegion { get; set; }
        public string CurrentSituation { get; set; }
        public int SalesForceSize { get; set; }
        public bool IsVerified { get; set; }
        //navigation properties
        public virtual ICollection<CategoryResult> CategoryResult { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QuestionResult> QuestionResult { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<Report> Report { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<SurveyResult> SurveyResult { get; set; }
        public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
        public int? OrganisationId { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

    }
```

Comment: try make a breakpoint on the line then debug it. then obeserve the value of your variable line by line by using Step Over(F10)

Comment: Try checking the resolutions in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839567/why-does-httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-return-blank.  It may be that windows auth is not enabled or the current user is not authenticated, this results in the nulls/blanks you are seeing.

Comment: Which item is null? e.g. in this line `qr.User.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();` is it `qr` or `qr.User` or `User` or `User.Identity`? If any one of these is null then you will get an error.

Comment: Hovering User.Identity.GetUserId() contains the id, but it is not setting it for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this::

```
var user = qr.User;
user.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

If the `QuestionResult` was already linked to a `User` then you would not be  changing which `User` is linked to the `QuestionResult`, you would be changing the `Id` of an existing `User` - and that is not allowed anyway.

But the `QuestionResult` is not already linked to a `User`. `qr.User` is null - so you get a null reference exception.

In general, life is much easier in Entity Framework if you add the foreign key to your model:

```
public class QuestionResult
{
   public string UserId { get; set; }

   public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

And now you can set the foreign key directly:

`qr.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();`

References:

[Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

[Making Do with Absent Foreign Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx)

Comment: but isn't the Id of an AppplicationUSer a Guid?

Answer (score 0):

So, do you wanna make foreing key for userid?

You can do like that:

```
    public int UserRefID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserRefID")]
    public xxx UserID { get; set; } //data name like ApplicationUser
```

And this error appear coz you have some problem about models or data classes.

Answer (score -1):

Set it as a string

Model:

```
public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
public string UserId { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
qr.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

And worked perfectly, even created foreign keys, that easy. Thanks so much!

Comment: Isn't this just a copy of Colin's earlier answer?

Comment: It was originally a guid, I posted it as a string, then Colin edited it, but i will remove my answer and make his answer the correct answer