# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name doesn't work in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

We recently upgraded our Visual Studio from 2010 to 2017. The code compiles and runs fine but all of a sudden the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name stopped working

It comes as blank.

What could change? Does it have anything to do with IIS Express?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are any of your referenced libraries broken after moving over?

Comment: @Mikhail What version of `.Net` are you targeting in your 2017 version of the project?

Comment: @Mikhail is windows authentication enabled? see this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839567/why-does-httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-return-blank

Comment: tokyo0709 - No
Ryan, targeting 4.7.1 in Web.config, targeting 4.6.1 in project properties
Muayyad, I do have Windows authentication specified in the authentication section of web config and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name works fine when running in VS 2010

Comment: These kinds of issues are not caused by Visual Studio specifically - they are more likely to be related to .NET Framework versions. As such, please include those details (old version -> new version) in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me

Located the corresponding applicationhost.config in the solution folder

Found the following lines

```
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />
<add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />
```

Changed them to

```
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />
<add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />
```

Then added the following to web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />         
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You need to an option in to the config file to enable winforms authentication. It is not enabled by default

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" />
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Just tried switching from Windows to Forms, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The fix in .NET Core is similar to those mentioned above, but the change there would be in your "launchSettings.json" file.  Change windowsAuthentication and anonymousAuthentication from:

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false, 
  "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:<your port number>",
    "sslPort": 0
  }
},
```

To:

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": true, 
  "anonymousAuthentication": false, 
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:<your port number>",
    "sslPort": 0
  }
},
```